# Office JavaScript Web Plugin not updating

Tags: javascript, plugins, ms-word, office-js

I am quite new to developing plugins for Office. I am hitting a brick wall and would really appreciate some help:

1. When I side-load my plugin, the plugin loads for the first time, but then it is stuck and any changes I make don't register, and Word doesn't load the new updates from the updated functions.js
2. If I delete (move) the manifest file, the plugin still appears in Word; where is this stored, and how can I get rid of it?
3. When I put debug flags in my code to do console.log ... where does this actually output to ? My functions are all set to buttons on the toolbar and I don't use the home.html to open a taskpane.

Comment: See if this article helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/testing-and-troubleshooting#changes-to-static-files-such-as-javascript-html-and-css-do-not-take-effect

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am running into the same situation while working on an Outlook plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The add-in is cached by Office. To remove the cached data delete the content of the folder `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef`

If you have npx installed you can remove add-ins via `npx office-toolbox remove`
install npx using `npm install -g npx`